# Magento 2 Transfer link.phtml to my own theme

Tags: magento2

I've created a Magento 2 theme.

I'd like to modify this file but transfering it to my own theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/link.phtml
```

My question is:

Where do I transfer it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go in `{theme-dir}/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/advanced/link.phtml`.